# Meta Data Column Name doesn't match with source column name in Informatica power center

Tags: oracle12c, informatica-powercenter, flatfilesource

I am loading data from a CSV Flat File in to target oracle DB using Informatica. The Flat file contains Arabic Column Names and i happen to create the table with similar column names using double quotes.But when running the map it gives me the above error i.e. Meta Data Column doesn't match with source column names.

If i change the column names to English in target table things are fine.

I found out that it is currently a bug in Informatica and will be resolved in the next release.
We are using Informatica 10.2 and oracle 12c as target.

Comment: Good to know, thanks! Would you care to post some more information about the bug?